# Node depth in randomly built binary search tree

Tags: binary-trees, probability-theory, search-trees

It can be proved that randomly built binary search trees of size $n$ are of depth $O(\log n)$ and it is clear that level $k$ has at most $2^{k}$ nodes (root's level is 0).

I have an algorithm that traverses every path in the tree (beginning at the root) but stops after traversing $k$ nodes (the parameter $k$ is a configurable parameter which is independent of the size of the tree $n$).

For any tree $T$ with $\mathit{depth}(T) > k$, the algorithm will miss some nodes of the tree. I would like to bound the probability of my algorithm missing a large number of nodes.

Formalizing it: let $T$ be a randomly built binary search tree of $n$ nodes.  I would like to calculate the probability for a node to have depth larger than $k$, as a function of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: I suggest you start by trying to learn about the proof of the fact that the average height is $O(\log n)$, and see if you can adapt any of those proof techniques to your situation.  Another approach might be to use linearity of expectation; if you can compute the probability that a given number ends up at depth larger than $k$, you can compute the expected number of such nodes.

Comment: I could additionally suggest you to look at the Catalan numbers (Cn) -- the number of correct bracket sequences (CBS) of length 2n. Each such sequence defines a non-isomorphic binary tree with nodes either having 0 or 2 children. You can look at the proof for the analytic formula for these numbers and adapt it to account only for CBS whose depth exceeds k. Let's call it Dn. Then the probability is Dn / Cn. Sure it doesn't account for nodes with one child, but it will be a good estimate of the overall thing.

Comment: @IS3NY I think the OP and you are thinking about different definitions of random binary trees. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree#Binary_trees_from_random_permutations) for OP's definition.

Comment: Using the [description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_binary_tree#Expected_depth_of_a_node) you should be able to compute not only the expected depth of a vertex (which depends on its location in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the values used to generate the tree), but also the variance, as well as higher moments. This would be a good start.